Bucle FOR no se cierra en C a pesar de empezar en i=0
Tengo que realizar una práctica para la Universidad y estoy teniendo un problema.
Tengo que indicar por pantalla dos restaurantes que hayamos introducido. Para ello me piden realizar una acción en la cual introduzcamos los datos manualmente guardandolos (acción leerRestaurante) y posteriormente debemos mostrar por pantalla los datos introducidos en la acción anterior (mostrarRestaurante). El caso es que cuando creo ambos bucles for con la acción correspondiente, al ejecutar el programa y realizar el primer bucle for, me pide los datos de ambos restaurantes y cuando introduzco el segundo, vuelve a iniciar el bucle for, no pasando al siguiente bucle for de mostrar por pantalla los datos introducidos.
Dejo por aquí abajo el código por si podeis encontrar el error que hace que no se cierre el primer bucle.
Muchas gracias.
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//Definimos las constantes con las que vamos a trabajar
#define MAX_RESTAURANTES 2
//introducimos la estructura con la que vamos a trabajar en el programa
typedef struct {
    char nombre[12]; //los caracteres máximos serán 12
    float importe; // importe del menu que puede contener decimales
    int estrellas; // numero de estrellas michelin que puede ser 0
} tRestaurante;
//Implementamos las acciones y funciones para que se usen en nuestro programa
void readRestaurante (tRestaurante *restaurante);
void mostrarRestaurante (tRestaurante restaurante);
    
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    
    int i;
    tRestaurante Restaurante[MAX_RESTAURANTES];
    
    
    printf("INPUT\n");
    for (i=0; i<MAX_RESTAURANTES; i++) {
        printf("RESTAURANT %i\n", i);
        readRestaurante(&Restaurante[i]);
    }
    
    printf("OUTPUT\n");
    printf("THE BEST RESTAURANT IS:\n");
    for(i=0; i<MAX_RESTAURANTES; i++){
        mostrarRestaurante(Restaurante[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}


//Debemos introducir una acción para leer los datos de los restaurantes

void readRestaurante (tRestaurante *restaurante) {
    printf("NAME?\n");
    scanf("%s", restaurante->nombre);
    printf("PRICE MENU?\n");
    scanf("%f", &restaurante->importe);
    printf("MICHELIN STARS\n");
    scanf("%i", &restaurante->estrellas);
}

void mostrarRestaurante (tRestaurante restaurante){
    printf("NAME: %s\n", restaurante.nombre);
    printf("PRICE MENU: %.2f\n", restaurante.importe);
    printf("MICHELIN STARS: %i\n", restaurante.estrellas);
    
}



El código funciona correctamente. Haz un [mre]. No tiene nada que ver que quede espacio en blanco ya que ese problema aparece solo cuando se utiliza scanf seguido de gets.

Si lees la página del manual de la función scanf, lo primero que te encuentras es lo siguiente:

   DESCRIPTION

   The  scanf() family of functions scans input like sscanf(3), but read from a FILE.  It is very difficult to
   use these functions correctly, and it is preferable to read entire lines with fgets(3)  or  getline(3)  and
   parse them later with sscanf(3) or more specialized functions such as strtol(3).


En tu caso, al introducir nombres con espacios scanf se lia y a partir de ahí los retornos de carro que se usan para indicar el final de la entrada dejan de coincidir. Siguiendo las indicaciones de la página del manual, puedes re-implementar tu función readRestaurante así:
void readRestaurante (tRestaurante *restaurante) {
  char tmp[256];
  
  printf("NAME?\n");
  fgets (restaurante->nombre, 12, stdin);
  restaurante->nombre[strlen(restaurante->nombre) - 1] = 0;
  printf("PRICE MENU?\n");
  fgets (tmp, 256, stdin);
  sscanf (tmp, "%f", &restaurante->importe);
  printf("MICHELIN STARS\n");
  fgets (tmp, 256, stdin);
  sscanf (tmp, "%d", &restaurante->estrellas);
}

Leyendo los datos de esta forma puedes sanearlos mucho mejor. Alternativamente puedes utilizar strtol y strtof te da un control más fino de los posibles errores.
